# Make a "Super User External Hard Drive" that can install 3 OSes?

Tags: windows-7, macos, ubuntu, partitioning, refit

I'm a webmaster in a student media and I've been asked to take care of the computer park. It's not my specialty, but I do like that and willing to do it, so I went on and say yes. Happy me ! Now I'm trying to make myself a perfect tool : since we have computers that runs OS X, Windows and Ubuntu, I want to make myself an external HDD that can be use to install new computers and perform administrative tasks.

My plan was the following, with a 3 tb USB 3 HDD :

- 1 partition in ExFAT on which I can have programs and backup images of different computer;
- 1 partition formatted in HFS+ on which I'd have the OS X installer;
- 1 partition on which I'd have Windows 7 installer;
- and finally, a last partition with Ubuntu 12.04 installed as a Live "CD" that I could run at will, or install if I wanted to.

So far, my ExFat partition is fine. I have my HFS+ partition that I am able to boot and install OS X on Machintoshes (faily easy : just restore the DMG onto the partition). I read somewhere that I only needed to copy Windows's ISO files on my partition and set it as active for it to become and installer, so I did. And I used LinuxLive USB Creator to make the Ubuntu partition.

Of course, it didn't work completely. As I said, OS X Installer is fine, but it seems I can't boot anything else. I then installed rEFIt onto my OS X partition. I can now see the Windows partition, but I can't start the installer with it, and the Ubuntu won't even appear in rEFIt.

Now, before I start to dig deeper into all of this:

1. Do you think this little idea of mine is feasible?
2. If so, do you have any ideas on how I could do that successfully?

Thank you all!

Comment: Are all of your machines on a network? I'd suggest creating a PXE server for reimaging windows / linux machines, and a Netboot server for the Macs. You can then create a Samba or NFS mount point for all the tools you'll need, instead of the hard drive. That way you won't even need to get out of your chair, just mount the network drive.

Comment: Another alternative. Checkout Zalman's external enclosure. Put ISO's on the drive, and then they show up as a virtual cdrom drive to the computer. We have one at work, and it is great. http://www.zalman.co.kr/eng/product/Product_Read.php?Idx=674

Comment: @spuder they're indeed on a network, just not the same. Basically, I have almost half my computers in a network somewhere, and the other somewhere else, with the university's network between the two locations. Although, I could make two scrap computer for theses servers, I'll be looking into this solution soon to see if it's doable!

Comment: @spuder that drive does looks awesome. does it work out of an OS, at boot? (I'd guess that yes :P)

Comment: It has a screen and a scroll button that lets you choose which ISO to use. When you plug it into the computer, it shows up in the bios as a CD Rom drive. Your computer can't tell the difference.

Comment: I'll be hunting of of theses soon enough, that's for sure! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managing a collection of computers is a common use case.

While setting up a utility usb hard drive is a good idea, there are some alternatives that are worth looking into.

**Custom Hardware**

Checkout virtual cd roms.

At my work, we have a [Zalman external Drive](http://www.zalman.co.kr/eng/product/Product_Read.php?Idx=674). Simply drop ISO's onto the drive, then select CdRom mode in the onscreen display. Your computer will then boot off the ISO exactly as if you had a real cd rom drive connected.

**Network Options**

You could save yourself from having to walk around to each computer, by moving some of your tools to a network. Here are some of the tools we use at my work.

- PXE Network boot for linux and windows installation - [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preboot_Execution_Environment)
- Netboot to troubleshoot, format Mac computers - [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBoot)
- Create a network mount that contains all the tools and data you need - [link](http://www.synology.com/us/index.php)
- Partitioning software  - [acronis](http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/diskdirector/) works great on windows machine, you can even create snapshots
- Hypervisor - Virtualize your servers with [proxmox](http://www.proxmox.com).
- Easily create PXE and network storage servers with [turnkeylinux](http://www.proxmox.com)
- Manage linux servers with [rundeck](http://rundeck.org)
- Automate with [puppet](http://puppetlabs.com)

Comment: I'm curently playing with Proxmox, this gives me hours to play ! ;-) And we're going to go with the Zalman for quickly deploying ISOs!

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do this with [YUMI](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/), or one if its clones.

It can be used to create a Multiboot USB Flash Drive containing multiple operating systems, antivirus utilities, disc cloning, diagnostic tools, and more. Contrary to MultiBootISO's which used grub to boot ISO files directly from USB, YUMI uses syslinux to boot extracted distributions stored on the USB device, and reverts to using grub to Boot Multiple ISO files from USB, if necessary.

Comment: I'll be checking in to this tomorrrow, I'll get back if it worked well or not! :)

Comment: Looking more closely at YUMI, it would be great for Ubuntu, since the Live version can also be installed. But for OS X & Windows, that won't work. I'm not actually looking to run the OSes from the HDD, only start the installs for it.

Comment: thats what this does.  you load the ISOs on the the disk, and it will boot the ISO you select.

Comment: I can't upvote this, I don't have enough reputation on superuser, still, I want to give credits to this answers. Even though it's not my favorite answer, it does work fine!